# Join 2 collections using put and keep the values of both within the same key using Laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, collections

I have 2 quite simple collections (The first has 2 values within the array products and the second is a simple array):

```
$ collection_1 = collect ([
     'products' => [
         ['id' => 1, 'name' => 'Product 1'], ['id' => 2, 'name' => 'Product 2']
     ]
]);

$ collection_2 = collect ([
         ['id' => 4, 'name' => 'Product 4'], ['id' => 3, 'name' => 'Product 4']
]);
```

What I want to do is merge both collections using put (keeping the key products) but when using put I lose the values of the first collection and only get those of the second:

```
$collection_1->put('products', $collection_2);
```

Result:

```
{"products":[{"id":4,"name":"Product 4"},{"id":3,"name":"Product 4"}]}
```

How can I join both collections while maintaining the values both in the array "products"? This is the expected result:

```
{"products":[{"id":1,"name":"Product 1"},{"id":2,"name":"Product 2"},{"id":4,"name":"Product 4"},{"id":3,"name":"Product 4"}]}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The put method just sets the value at the specified key, so it will overwrite what's there. If you want to keep all the values, merge the values from the first collection into the second.

```
$collection_2->merge($collection_1->get('products'));
```

Then you can use put like you're doing now.

```
$collection_1->put('products', $collection_2);
```